# Where can I find this .NET WinForms control (if it exists)?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, controls

I've seen this control in applications, and not just dreamed it, right?

[image: my dream control]

- There are two list-boxes, left and right.
- Left-box contains a list of possible selections
- Right-box contains the selected items.
- Right-box may contain duplicates.
- Right-left controls between the two boxes allow adding from right-to-left, or deletion from the right.
- up-down controls to the right of the right-box allows for re-ordering of a selected item.
- Standard WinForms. VS2010 and 4.0 runtime, if it makes a difference.

Comment: There is no control created already for you. You'll have to invent one using ListBoxs, Buttons, and glue code. The important question is: how did you created that mockup - what program gives that hand-drawn look?

Comment: WinForms?  WPF?  Either way, it's not too hard to create yourself as a user control.

Comment: @Ian: There are some software packages for UI mockup that use that style.  Pretty good for working with end users.

Comment: @Ian, this mockup looks like it was made with a freely available Firefox add-on called Pencil. (Available as a standalone application, too.)

Comment: @IanBoyd Balsamiq http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups

Comment: Good eye, @stakx -- I used Pencil: http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx

Comment: Winforms, @Eric-J. So I updated the question.

Comment: Heh.  I've built this control two or three times in my career, on both ASP.NET as well as WinForms, but never consolidated it into a control.  Thanks @stakx for mentioning Pencil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the control [here.](https://code.google.com/p/winforms-custom-select-control/)

This is a new control, inspired by [this WPF control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36624/Multiple-Selection-Control) and [this asp.net project.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8219/Enhanced-List-Box-Control)

Thanks to everybody that pointed out existing projects, and suggested building my own.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, no such control exists. You can make it yourself from two [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx?ppud=4) controls and a few buttons or try to adapt existing sources like the one Justin came up to or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36624/Multiple-Selection-Control)

Comment: I can't get that project to build on my machine, and I'm not familiar enough (at all) with WPF to solve the issue, or add the features I want. thanks, though. I'm building my own Custom Control with ideas from this and @JustinPihony's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to find somebody who has a free version of this implemented somewhere. However, this is usually just multiple controls put together with custom logic to match the rules that you specified. But, again, you might be able to find somebody who has turned this into a custom control; it is just not a default part of the Visual Studio toolbox.

A quick search found a code project solution that looks like it might work for you?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8219/Enhanced-List-Box-Control

Comment: Dang. I've seen this format in several applications, so I had hoped it was pre-made. I hate re-inventing the wheel, when all I want to do is drive to the mall.

Comment: That looks like a great time-saving first-approximation! I've never search CodeProject directly, only getting there through Google (I was image-searching in this case). Will have to remember to search there. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest looking at the code project control. Or, you could create the control yourself and then it will be reusable later. And, then you could post your own solution to the world and maybe save somebody else in the future from having to re-create the wheel :). Also, dont forget to upvote and accept if you like the response :)

Comment: Hey, at least it isnt totally reinventing the wheel :)